# draggable overlay on touch screen in google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, touch-event

I used this gmap api code for building overlay div with image: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/QRuW8/. it works for desktop with mouse, but not working with touch event. please, help me.

I tried to do it next:

google.maps.event.addDomListener(container,
'touchstart',
function(e){
this.style.cursor='move';
that.map.set('draggable',false);
that.set('origin',e);

```
        that.moveHandler  = google.maps.event.addDomListener(that.get('map').getDiv(),
            'touchmove',
            function(e){
                let touch = e.touches[0] || e.changedTouches[0];
                var origin = that.get('origin'),
                    left   = origin.clientX-touch.clientX,
                    top    = origin.clientY-touch.clientY,
                    pos    = that.getProjection()
                        .fromLatLngToDivPixel(that.get('position')),
                    latLng = that.getProjection()
                        .fromDivPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(pos.x-left,
                            pos.y-top));
                that.set('origin',e);
                that.set('position',latLng);
                that.draw();
            });

    }
);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(container,'touchancel',function(e){
    that.map.set('draggable',true);
    this.style.cursor='default';
    google.maps.event.removeListener(that.moveHandler);
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(container,'touchend',function(e){
    that.map.set('draggable',true);
    this.style.cursor='default';
    google.maps.event.removeListener(that.moveHandler);
});
```

but it doesn't work. what do I make wrong? thanks